# Something "vous donne droit à" something else : missing verb (avoir) ?

Tags: grammaire, locutions

Today I received an email from Amazon with some kind of a discount. I decided to make use of it and translate it, however I stumbled on a sentence that gives me problems:

> Votre commande récente sur Amazon.fr vous donne droit à un code promotionnel que vous pourrez utiliser lors de votre prochain achat éligible.

I know what the sentence is about however I think that it is missing a verb between **donne** and **droit** since *having a right to something* should be *avoir droit à qc*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Donner droit à quelque chose" is actually a valid and commonly used construction roughly meaning "to be eligible for something".

I personally like [Linguee](http://www.linguee.fr/francais-anglais/traduction/donner+droit.html) to search for expressions and to get examples of translations. Googling "donner droit" (with quotes) also turns up examples:

- [Être ex-président ne doit pas **donner droit** à des places réservées](http://www.liberation.fr/france/2013/01/08/etre-ex-president-ne-doit-pas-donner-droit-a-des-places-reservees_872576)
- [Au Québec, les frais que vous payez pour la garde de votre enfant peuvent vous **donner droit** au crédit d’impôt pour frais de garde d’enfants.](http://www4.gouv.qc.ca/FR/Portail/Citoyens/Evenements/immigrer-au-quebec/Pages/credit-impot-frais-garde.aspx)

Comment: Voir aussi directement la locution aux dictionnaires [_TLFi_](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/droit) et [_Larousse_](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/droit/26842/locution?q=donner+droit#154988). Merci.

Answer (score 2):

**Donne** is the verb you're looking for:

```
Votre commande vous donne droit à un code promotionnel.
Your order entitles you (gives you the right) to a promotional code.
```